# Review queue and already flagged question

Tags: support, specific-question, flagging, review

I just spotted [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56984/i-am-getting-approximately-6-errors-in-this-binarytree-implementation-and-id-li) and flagged it off topic, as it contained non-working code.

Some time later I checked the review queue and this same question popped up.

I thought about what to do. Clicking <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> came to my mind, because I already flagged it as off topic, but as this is not the meaning of this button, I then just clicked on <kbd>Skip</kbd>.

What would be the right way to review in such a case?

Comment: In which review queue did it appear and what were your options?

Comment: First post review queue. The Flag as `off topic` has been greyed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only other thing that I may have done (depending on how long the question had been there after you flagged it) is Down Vote the question or if not entirely worthy of a down vote you could have commented on the question about why you think it is off-topic.

I would have also posted the share link in [The Second Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) so that the Mods and the Regulars could read the question and decide if it is truly off-topic.

so three things, two of which will give you credit for the review.

1. Comment
2. Up vote a comment already in place
3. DownVote (***only if it is a truly bad question, that cannot be saved through edits***)
4. Post share link in [The Second Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) chat room

Comment: As I already have upvoted @Simon André Forsberg's comment I didn`t see option 1 for me. As the OP states that there are errors shown, it was clear for me that the question has been off topic. So only option 2 would have been the route to go. But sharing the link in the chat is a good thing for other posts where I am not sure. Btw. I don't care about credits ;-)

Comment: you should be able to Comment on most of the posts shown in the review queues.  I think the low quality queue is the only one where you can't comment, and I don't think you have access to that one yet.

Comment: Yes, I know but i didn't wanted to add a duplicate comment as Simon's had been sufficient.

Comment: oh I see what you are saying...lol I misunderstood.  if you upvote a comment, I think that counts as well (for review credit)